# Как получить json?

Tags: javascript, json, url

Попросил человека помочь с серверной частью для игры(он должен был сделать json,размещенный в облаке,а также python script для обработки)
Я запрашиваю топ-лист игроков с помощью javaScript,но его json размещенный по ссылке https://leadeboards.herokuapp.com/getlist не загружается(выдает всегда error)
*К query прибегать не хочется,потому что всё гораздо проще решается*
Код:

```
var xhrURL = 'https://leadeboards.herokuapp.com/getlist';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', xhrURL);
xhr.responseType = 'json';

xhr.onload = function(){
var a = xhr.response;
alert(a)
}

xhr.onerror = function(){
alert('error')
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Политика CORS не дает возможности делать запросы с другого хоста. [Хром про CORS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Comment: CORS настраивается на сервере. Только вот у меня этот запрос и без CORS не открывается) Упал?

Comment: @vp_arth у меня все открывается, если вводите эту строку в браузере какая ошибка?

Comment: У меня тоже уже всё открывается(см. ответ), просто тупил полторы минуты чего-то.

Comment: тут рекомендации как включить cors на вашем сервере https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980713/solve-cross-origin-resource-sharing-with-flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока товарищ настраивает CORS, можете пользоваться прокси:

```js
const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const url = 'https://leadeboards.herokuapp.com/getlist';
fetch(`${proxy}${url}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Спасибо,помогло!Это-решение...